# Updated Samsung galaxy A5 to Marshmallow but look and feel remains that of Lollipop

Tags: samsung, 6.0-marshmallow, device-firmware, samsung-galaxy-a5

I have a Samsung galaxy A5 (SM-A500H) I didn't get a notification for an update from settings so I grabbed android 6.0.1 from [Sammobile](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/database/SM-A500H/), I downloaded the South African version since there's no version for my country.

Everything is working and if I go to settings about phone, I see it's 6.0.1 and if I tap I get the marshmallow logo and the game that looks like flappy bird. And everything is working.

But it still feels like Lollipop. The color is still blue rather than black, the marshmallow themes and wallpapers are missing. When the phone boots I don't see the marshmallow animation, the scrolling in the app drawer is horizontal not vertical etc.

Is there a way to verify that what I'm using is really marshmallow? Could it be a knockoff?

Comment: May be if it is some knockoff, they may not have changed the API level to prevent app issues. Download some app like `Dev Tools` from play store and see if the `API Level` is reporting 23 (Marshmellow).

Comment: @beeshyams i guess you'd call it dirty since I didn't remove lollipop, i just upgraded to marshmallow without uninstalling anything

Comment: @Madushan dev tools says `api level 23, codename marshmallow,  version 6.0.1 `  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.becomputer06.adt&hl=en

Comment: @beeshyams and yes odin 3.11 by strictly following the instructions here http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/download/90719/A500HXXU1CPH8_A500HOJV1CPH4_XFE/

Comment: @beeshyams ok will let you know when im done, this time im downloading the Kazakhstan version

Comment: I think you should go with AndyYan's answer- sorry, I wasn't aware of this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lower-end phones usually won't get the new manufacturer skin (that's on the new flagship phone) with a new Android version.

As for the launcher, bootanimation and stuff, it's how Samsung chose to make it in their TouchWiz skin - they don't necessarily follow how Google do it on Nexus.

Try installing Google Now Launcher if you want the vertical scrolling experience. Not looking as harmonious on top of all the TouchWiz icons but better than nothing.

Comment: so no need for a clean flash?

Comment: @Lynob Trying doesn't hurt, but clean flash shouldn't change the fact. A firmware from a different region has a possibility although that's also marginal.

Comment: @AndyYan: This is new to me ! Specific for low end devices?

Comment: @beeshyams Also to old (>1 year) flagships. For example Note 4 never got Note 5's new UX officially, thus its bump to Lollipop appears largely unchanged at first sight. With a jump as subtle from Lollipop to Marshmallow, it'll be even less obvious.

Comment: Thanks..wasn't aware of this. In which case my answer may not help much- Note 2 was my last (4 years) +1

Comment: you are correct but i had to clean flash just because i had permission issues but you are correct

Comment: @beeshyams i had to clean flash though. but he is correct about the look and feel

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Undeleted the answer as it was useful in solving permission issues

Answer (score 0):

in API 23(Marshmallow) Android apps should request permissions at runtime so all you need is open an app that uses your location or reading your sd card

try with google maps or download and install file explorer apps

and when you run the app you can see a dialog pops up for requesting permissions

[image]